# Yii 1.1 relationship search issue

Tags: yii, yii1.x

**1. Table `meeting`**

Model name `CoreMeeting`

Fields `id, title, start time, created_by`

Relationship:

```
'MeetingParticipants' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MeetingParticipants', 'meeting_id'),
```

**2. Table `core_meeting_participant`**

Model name is `meeting_participant`

Fields are `id, meeting_id, participant_id, group_id`

Relationship:

```
 'meeting' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'CoreMeeting', 'meeting_id'),
 'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MeetingGroup', 'group_id'),
```

**3. Table `core_meeting_group`**

Model name is `MeetingGroup`

Fields are `id, group_name`

My search filter in the meeting model is:

```
public function search()
{
    
    $group=filter_var($_REQUEST['group'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);//contain group name

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
    $criteria->with=array('MeetingParticipants'=>array("select"=>"*"),'MeetingParticipants.group'=>array('select'=>'id,group_name'));
    
    if(isset($this->start_time) && !empty($this->start_time))
    $criteria->compare('start_time',date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->start_time)), true);

    $criteria->compare('created_by',$user_id);

    if(isset($group)&&!empty($group))
    $criteria->compare('group.group_name',$group);
    $criteria->together = true;


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,

    ));
}
```

I have created 4 meetings, each meeting have at least 5 participants each participant belongs to a meeting group. I want to list all meetings with the following filed meeting title, groups and meeting time.

My problem is if I enable `$criteria->together = true;` if the meeting has more than 10 participants that will show only 1 meeting in grid view. If I disable this that will show all but I can't search with the meeting name.
SQL fiddle link is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdaacf
full SQL dump https://pastebin.com/NtpMuCpE

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for `CDbCriteria`->`together` property:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#together-detail

Whether the foreign tables should be joined with the primary table in a single SQL. **This property is only used in relational AR queries for HAS_MANY and MANY_MANY relations.**

As I can see your relation in `CoreMeeting` model:

**'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MeetingGroup', 'group_id')**

Obviously you are trying to fetch one-to-one (BELONGS_TO) relation `CoreMeeting` -> `MeetingGroup` eagerly by globally setting to your `CDbCriteria`->`together` = true; which is not correct according to the documentation.

What I would suggest you, first of all get rid of this global `together` setting to `CDbCriteria` and try changing your with clause like this:

```
$criteria->with = [
    // this is your has-many relation (one meeting has several participants), thus we set here `together` to true
    'MeetingParticipants' => [
        'together' => true,
        'with' => [
            // this is your one-to-one relation (one participant has one group)
            'group'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: not working no diffrence check sql fiddle link is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdaacf
full sql dump https://pastebin.com/NtpMuCpE

Comment: In fact, I think that the issue is not related to SQL after I saw your database structure. Did you remove the global $criteria->together = true; ? What do you mean by no difference, are the results now aggregated or the search is not working? Please give more specific details what happened after you've changed your code.

Comment: hi please visit the link for the out put when made changes https://imagebin.ca/v/5JIYEeb0Um3l

Comment: check this for if  remove the criteria together this is the required out put but cant do search https://pasteboard.co/J42GnsT.png

Comment: $criteria->group = 't.id';

Try adding this line. It will group by CoreMeeting identifier primary key which will prevent aggregation from the HAS_MANY relation and guarantee uniqueness to the primary model.

Comment: that show error CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'portalv2.MeetingParticipants.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. The

Comment: Yes, you should explicitly describe the columns in the group clause like you have describe them in the select clause, i have just pointed you that you should group by the primary key of the CoreMeeting model (core_meeting table). Just check how is defined in the select clause.

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: Hi check the sql t.id already exist  there COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `. Im new to yii so i dont know how to explicitly specify id  in yii .can you help me?

Comment: Behind the scenes, this is the SQL produced from the ActiveDataProvider in order to query the total count of the result set. In most cases in looks similar to the main query from the CDbCriteria wrapped in select count(*) from ( CDbCriteria->rawSql ). That is what i meant, if you group by t.id in your CDbCriteria query it will change the total count result set because group by will break down the aggregation which came from the join with the HAS_MANY relation.

Comment: What do you mean by "new issue"?

Comment: how to reslove thie error : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'portalv2.MeetingParticipants.id?

Comment: $criteria->group = 't.id, core_meeting_participant.id';

Comment: not working like expected  https://pasteboard.co/J4cMNDo.png  checkout this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211860/discussion-between-g-spirov-and-reneesh-kurian).